# Firestore in Swift - Listener producing needless reads

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that uses a snapshot listener to listen to data in a particular document. However, when a field in the document is updated, the data is read 7-10x over. Never read once, and never read the number of fields that are in my document, it always seems to be an arbitrary number. Also, when the read data prints out, it seems like every printout is the same except for a couple of fields that I'm not setting (like an array prints out "<__NSArrayM 0x282d9f240>" but the number changes on each print). As a result, minimal usage of my app is causing 5-10k reads. I'm trying to reduce the number of reads and I don't know exactly how, but the app has to read as data is updated, but my two questions are:

1. when I print the data from the listener, does each data print out signify a separate read operation? and
2. is there any way for the listener to be alerted of the update but wait to actually perform the read until the data is updated, then perform one read instead of multiple reads every time any field is updated? Or another strategy to reduce reads when multiple writes occur?

Not sure if this is helpful, but here is the code I'm using to perform the read...its pretty much the standard code from the firestore sdk:

```
 env.db.collection(env.currentSessionCode!).document(K.FStore.docName).addSnapshotListener { [self] documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching snapshot: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
                        

            self.env.data1 = data[K.FStore.data1] as? String ?? "????"
            self.env.data2 = data[K.FStore.data2] as? String ?? "????"
            self.env.data3 = data[K.FStore.data3] as? [String] ?? ["????"]
            self.env.data4 = data[K.FStore.data4] as? [String] ?? ["????"]
            self.env.data5 = data[K.FStore.data5] as? Double ?? 0
            self.env.data6 = data[K.FStore.data6] as? Double ?? 0
            self.env.data7 = data[K.FStore.data7] as! Bool
            self.env.data8 = data[K.FStore.data8] as! Bool
            
            print("Current data: \(data)")
```

Update - For clarification, the way I have been updating my data to firebase is with a environment object, and using "didSet" when the new data is changed/updated in the environment to update it on firebase...I think this might be the root of the problem, as the function called on didSet runs 4-5 times each time it is called...

relevant code:

```
@Published var data1: String {
        didSet {
            postValuesToFB(fb: K.FStore.data1, string: data1)
        }
    }

    func postValuesToFB(fb: String, string: String) {
        guard let code = currentSessionCode else {
            fatalError("Error - Connection Check - no value for current session code in Global Env")
        }
        
        let docRef = db.collection(code).document(K.FStore.docName)
        docRef.getDocument { document, _ in
            guard let document = document else {
                return
            }
            if document.exists {
                let session = self.db.collection(code).document(K.FStore.docName)

                session.updateData([
                    fb: string,
                    K.FStore.dateLastAccessed: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                ])

                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you tracking when new listeners are added? Do you have any code that removes listeners after they have been added and no longer needed?

Comment: no, is there a way to do that/any documentation on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, removing listeners is covered in the documentation.

Comment: Why are you adding a listener in the first place? Are you wanting to be notified of future changes or do you want to just read the data once? Also, do you write or change the data in that document at any point? Are you recursively calling that code from a function - perhaps a tableView delegate function?

Comment: im trying to keep a view up to date with data from a document, and update the view whenever the document changes...

Comment: When I run your code, I get one and only one document read. That being said, your Firebase structure is unknown to us, which is why I asked you to include it. That tells me you're calling that code multiple times (multiple listeners) and/or data within that document is being modified elsewhere in your code. It would probably be a good idea to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if the two answers from the Firebaser's don't resolve the issue. And yes, if you see multiple prints of *Current data* that indicates multiple reads/events.

Comment: @Jay sorry, the project im working on is lengthy and I'm not quite sure what code to include without including everything...

the way my firebase data is structured is the app will look for a collection with a particular code as created by the app earlier, and then listen to one of two documents in that collection for changes. Several fields of the document get changed in quick succession, but what makes no sense is that 30 or so triggered write changes in the document will show up as 300 read/write changes in usage, and I can't quite figure out why the listener is updating so many times...

Comment: The issue is the code in the question works for us, not for you, which means there is some difference in the code *outside of the code in the question*. If you want an accurate answer, we need to duplicate the issue. Check elsewhere in your code for calls to the code in your question, code that modified the database, etc. If your seeing that print statement repeatedly, then either other code is calling it over and over, or stuff is being changed in the database causing that code to fire.

Comment: @Jay I'm starting to put some print statements inside my code, basically on the "didSet" statements, to try and see if the number of calls to firebase match the number of printouts from the didSet's...still trying to get to the bottom of this, because it only shows 3-4 printouts for the data, but the usage shows hundreds of reads :/

Comment: didSet will be unrelated to writing data or altering data in Firebase. You should be looking for `.setData`, `.addDocument`,`.updateData` and then look for any observers attached with `addSnapshotListener ` and work backward from there. In other words you could be attaching multiple listeners that all fire when a single event occurs OR you could be performing multiple changes to a node causing the event handler to fire repeatedly.

Comment: @Jay this is probably the most accurate answer...I placed some print statements on my didSet and it seems like the didSets fire 6-7x per button press, then the listener updates that many times as well...I only have one snapshot listener, that fires when my view loads (.onAppear in swiftui), but it just seems like a lot of writes are occurring, causing my listener to refresh a bunch...

Comment: *didSets fire 6-7x per button press* well, that would obviously be an issue. At least this appears to be unrelated to Firebase if something in your UI is causing the the issue.

Comment: yeah, i put prints on my buttons and they are only firing once per tap, but yeah i think my code needs some refactoring...ive been also debating switching to real time db since the amount of data i move is small, but it has to travel a lot back and forth for my app, and the pricing of rtdb makes more sense than cloud firestore...

Comment: I think changing databases as this juncture is a mistake and will add more confusion to the issue. You should correct this problem and once you understand why it's happening, then change databases if needed. The code works for us so it probably would not help any future readers because there's no problem with the code in the question.

Comment: I did some digging into my code and (essentially) used print statements on my "didSet's" on my properties, so i can track when the properties were actually changing. Long story short, my app was changing these properties a lot, so once I was able to wrangle the changes, everything started calming down a bit more. I did end up switching to realtime database, and I'm glad I did since my total data usage is much lower than my number of reads and writes at the end of the day. Thanks again for your help @Jay :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, it sounds as if you've written no code to remove a listener after it's been added.  Based on this, it's relatively safe to assume that your code could be adding many listeners over time, and **each one** is getting called for **each change**.

You should take a moment to think about the architecture of your app and figure out when is the appropriate time to remove listeners when they're no longer needed.  Usually this corresponds with the lifecycle of whatever component is responsible for display of the data from the query.  Review the documentation for [getting realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), especially the section on [detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).  It's up to you to determine the right time to remove your listener, but you definitely don't want to "leak" a listener as you are now.

Comment: If i detatch a listener, does that listener stay detached until I "reattach it", or is there a way to detatch the listener after the data updates and then "reattach it" after the data is done updating?

Comment: After you stop listening, it's done for good.  You have to query again to start over.

Comment: ok gotcha...the code im calling is being called on a "onAppear" for the view the data is being shown in...its a function that contains the code that adds the snapshot listener, and im not quite sure how to stop the listener or control when it listens :/

Comment: The documentation I linked shows how to stop a listener on a query.  If you have another question, please post it separately.

Answer (score 1):

A common source of unexpected read charges for developers who are new to Firestore is the Firebase console itself. When that console displays Firestore content, you are charged for those read too. To ensure you measure the impact of your code correctly, test it with the Firebase console closed.

> when I print the data from the listener, does each data print out signify a separate read operation?

Not really. You get charged for a document read, when the document is read on your behalf on the server. You are not charted for printing the same `DocumentSnapshot` multiple times.

> is there any way for the listener to be alerted of the update but wait to actually perform the read until the data is updated

Nope. To know the document has changed, the server needs to read it. So that requires a charged read operation.